# Could Windows 10 installed on AMD NVMe Raid be the cause of poor performance?

Tags: windows-10, raid, pci-express, nvme, amd-ryzen

I just built a computer at work that will be used to deal with loads of [SIARD](https://www.loc.gov/preservation/digital/formats/fdd/fdd000426.shtml) files. The configuration is as follows:

- Asus TRX40 Prime Pro (90MB12F0-M0EAY0) (latest 0902 bios but same results on 0702)
- Ryzen Threadripper 3960X
- 4 sticks of 32GB RAM (CMV32GX4M1A2666C18)
- 2 sticks of Corsair Force Series MP600 2TB (CSSD-F2000GBMP600) *these are running in AMD NVMe RAID*
- Seasonic Prime 800W
- RTX 2060 Super (GV-N206SGAMING OC-8GD) *sometimes we render stuff*

I have installed Windows 10 (latest update as of 02.06.2020) and I am not seeing expected performance. Boot to OS takes about 40 seconds and the system feels more like a 4700K Intel system on a SATA SSD.

I suspect this could have something to do with the RAID, but not entirely sure and I don't seem to find much information supporting this. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you done any performance benchmarks on the individual drives?  What about the RAID has a whole?  You have really provided the required information to diagnose your problem

Comment: As Ramhound suggested, it would be nice to see some numbers from a bemchmark application such as CrystalDiskMark to see what speeds your array or the individual drives are capable of in Windows.

Comment: Will be added during the day. It might just be that unraiding them solves the problem.